# Number formatting in c# - separate int and decimal parts

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to do something very similar to [this c# docs example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierEscape):

```
int value = 123;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(@"\#\#\# ##0 dollars and \0\0 cents \#\#\#"));
// Displays ### 123 dollars and 00 cents ###
```

Except I want it to actually work with decimals:

```
double value = 123.095;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(@"\#\#\# ##0 dollars and 0000 \#\#\#"));
// Should display ### 123 dollars and 0950 ###, but it doesn't (of course)
```

Tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(@"\#\#\# ##0. dollars and 0000 cents \#\#\#"));
```

But prints the decimal separator (of course), which I don't want.
I know I could do something like this:

```
String.Format("{0:##0} {1:0000}", 123, 123);
```

But would very much like to avoid unless there is no other way

Comment: `int value = 123.123;` you really not doing that :)

Comment: @Reniuz wrong copy/paste, obviously.

Comment: 123.095 is $123.00 dollars and depending how you determine the value between `09.5` cents and `10.00` cents.... it certainly isn't `0950` cents based on the comment.  I still have to give this question a downvote because of the amount of mistakes that had to be fixed.

Comment: There is no standard string format that can target the right side of the decimal for you so you'll have to go about it another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* define your own special currency format, but... I'm not sure if I would do this.  It kind of seems like an abuse of the NumberFormatInfo object:

EDIT: changed datatype of value from decimal to double

```
// works with either decimal or double
double value = 123.095;

var mySpecialCurrencyFormat = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();

mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 8;
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.NegativeSign = "-";
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencySymbol = "cents";
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 4;
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = " dollars and ";
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
mySpecialCurrencyFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes = new[] { 3 };


Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", mySpecialCurrencyFormat));
```

Output is "123 dollars and 0950 cents"

EDIT: it might make more sense to use CurrencyNegativePattern 15 instead of 8, so that negative values cause the entire string to be surrounded by parenthesis, which might be less confusing than just putting a negative sign in front of the dollars.  For example, using CurrencyNegativePattern = 15 causes -123.095 to be output as "(123 dollars and 0950 cents)"

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as it is only 9.5 cents rather than 950 cents. But I do enjoy your abuse of a number formatter.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - :) thanks for pointing that out regarding the 0950 cents...even though that's what the OP asked for, it does seem odd.

Comment: If the OP wanted to do something like output "123 dollars and 09.50 cents", then I think this answer would break down, because I don't see any way to provide "grouping" for the decimal portion of a number using NumberFormatInfo.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the author wants 950 cents instead of 9.5 cents?

Comment: Ok, I re-read the question, and it seems like the OP may not *necessarily* want to output "cents" at the end. The 2nd code example suggests that the OP might just want "123 dollars and 0950".

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice correct, I edited the question afterwards - sorry for the initial copy/paste fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve a correct separation using composite formatting in .Net. You'll have to separate the parts on your own:

```
decimal value = 123.23m;

Console.WriteLine(
    @"{0:0} dollars and {1:#0} cents",
    Math.Truncate(value),                 // Dollars
    (value - Math.Truncate(value)) * 100m // Cents
);

// Output: 123 dollars and 23 cents
```

As an aside, you should never use `float` or `double` to store money, unless you want IEEE-754 rounding modes to steal your money or cause you to owe more.

Comment: This seems like its the only correct answer to the author's question.

Comment: Can't use `decimal` in my case. Shame that I can't use composite formatting, either - thank you.

Comment: Take care with negative values

Comment: @Razor - Why on earth can you not use a decmial value?

Answer (score 0):

Write a program where the user enters a real number such as 12.842 and then outputs the integer part and the decimal part while using type casting to perform the required operation. 
Output would look something like:
The integer part is: 12
The decimal part is: 842